# Saving every permutation in Photoshop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, photoshop, photoshop-script

I know this has been answered previously for a set number of groups (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30768/combinations-and-permutations-of-photoshop-layers), however I had trouble implementing this for a variable number of groups.

My overall objective is to be able to save/export every permutation of layers, regardless of the number of groups.

I.E, if my layer structure was as such (all of the below are layerSets):

```
options
--one
----a
----b
----c
--two
----1
----2
----3
background
--base
--top
```

I would need to save images for a1, a2, a3, b1, b2 b3, c1, c2 and c3, each with individual names, while still keeping the background group untouched.

The problem I'm having is sometimes there will be 7 different options with 5 different choices below them and sometimes there will be 3 options with a number of choices below them.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I've racked my brain trying to solve this for quite some time now.

Comment: The code you linked to uses `app.activeDocument.artLayers.length` to get the number of layers; you'll have to check the documentation for a similar way to get the number of layer groups; something like `app.activeDocument.artLayerGroups.length` maybe?

Comment: I've found that using `app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("options").layerSets.length` returns the number of layer groups under options, and `app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("options").layerSets[i].layerSets.length` (i being the relevant index) returns the number of layer groups under the relevant sub-option.

Comment: That should give you all the information you need to generate the permutations. For a fixed number of main sets (like "one" and "two"), use nested loops that run through the options (a, b, c ... and 1, 2, 3 ...); for a variable number (if there can be a "three", "four" ...) use a recursive algorithm.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, I managed to get it working in the end. If you want to stick that in an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Cheers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you linked to uses `app.activeDocument.artLayers.length` to get the number of layers; as you have found, there is a similar way to get the layer sets, `app.activeDocument.layerSets` and a way to get to nested sets, `app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("options").layerSets`.
Together, these should enable you to retrieve all the information you need to traverse the layer structure and generate the permutations.

To toggle the visibility of the layers in a fixed number of sets (like "one" and "two" in your example), use nested loops that run through the options for each set (a, b, c ... and 1, 2, 3 ...).

For a variable number of sets (if there can be a "three", "four" ...) use a recursive algorithm, which loops through the options for the first set, and for each option recurses to loop through the options for each following set.